# execvp call in git's source for external shell cmd returns EFAULT (Bad address) errno, seemingly only in 64 bit. Googling reveals nothing

Tags: c, linux, git, errno, execvp

UPDATE: running git diff with valgrind results in

```
 Syscall param execve(argv) points to uninitialised byte(s)
```

And the output from `strace` is not fully decoded--i.e., there are hex numbers among the array of strings that is argv.

...

This started out like a superuser problem but it's definitely moved into SO's domain now.

But anyway, here is my original SU post detailing the problem before I looked at the source very much: https://superuser.com/questions/795751/various-methods-of-trying-to-set-up-a-git-diff-tool-lead-to-fatal-cannot-exec

Essentially, following standard procedure to set up vimdiff as a diff tool by setting the external directive under [diff] in .gitconfig leads to this errors like this:

```
fatal: cannot exec 'git_diff_wrapper': Bad address
external diff died, stopping at HEAD:switch-monitor.sh.
```

It happens on my Linux Mint 17 64 bit OS, as well as on an Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit OS on a virtualbox VM, *but not* in an Ubuntu 14.04 *32 bit* VM...

Googling reveals no similar problems.  I've spent a lot of time looking at git's source to figure this out.  Bad address is the description returned by `strerror` for an `EFAULT` error.  Here is a short description of `EFAULT` from execve manpage:

```
EFAULT filename points outside your accessible address space
```

I've tracked down how the error message is pieced together by git, and have used that to narrow down the source of the problem quite a bit.  Let's start here:

```
static int execv_shell_cmd(const char **argv)
{
    const char **nargv = prepare_shell_cmd(argv);
    trace_argv_printf(nargv, "trace: exec:");
    sane_execvp(nargv[0], (char **)nargv);
    free(nargv);
    return -1;
}
```

This function should not return control, but it does due to the error. The actual `execvp` call is in `sane_execvp`, but perhaps `prepare_shell_cmd` is of interest, though I don't spot any problems:

```
static const char **prepare_shell_cmd(const char **argv)
{
    int argc, nargc = 0;
    const char **nargv;

    for (argc = 0; argv[argc]; argc++)
        ; /* just counting */
    /* +1 for NULL, +3 for "sh -c" plus extra $0 */
    nargv = xmalloc(sizeof(*nargv) * (argc + 1 + 3));

    if (argc < 1)
        die("BUG: shell command is empty");

    if (strcspn(argv[0], "|&;<>()$`\\\"' \t\n*?[#~=%") != strlen(argv[0])) {
#ifndef GIT_WINDOWS_NATIVE
        nargv[nargc++] = SHELL_PATH;
#else
        nargv[nargc++] = "sh";
#endif
        nargv[nargc++] = "-c";

        if (argc < 2)
            nargv[nargc++] = argv[0];
        else {
            struct strbuf arg0 = STRBUF_INIT;
            strbuf_addf(&arg0, "%s \"$@\"", argv[0]);
            nargv[nargc++] = strbuf_detach(&arg0, NULL);
        }
    }

    for (argc = 0; argv[argc]; argc++)
        nargv[nargc++] = argv[argc];
    nargv[nargc] = NULL;

    return nargv;
}
```

It doesn't look like they messed up the terminating NULL pointer (the absence of which is known to cause EFAULT).

`sane_execvp` is pretty straightforward.  It's a call to `execvp` and returns -1 if it fails.

I haven't quite figured out what `trace_argv_printf` does, though it looks like it might would affect `nargv` and maybe screw up the terminating NULL pointer?  If you'd like me to include it in this post, let me know.

I have been unable to reproduce an EFAULT with `execvp` in my own C code thus far.

This is git 1.9.1, and the source code is available here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.9.1.tar.gz

Any thoughts on how to move forward?

Thanks

Comment: A better description of `EFAULT` is the one found in the execve man page: "filename or one of the pointers in the vectors argv or envp points outside your accessible address space". Check that these are in fact pointing to valid locations. As usual, gdb is your friend -- or valgrind, if you want to try for tooling that might be able to point out the root cause more effectively.

Comment: Updated the EFAULT description.  So I should compile git from source with debug symbols to run with gdb?

Comment: If your distribution doesn't have a package with debug symbols separately available; almost all modern distros in both Red Hat-derivative and Debian-derivative families do. (Modern toolchains allow the debug symbols to be in separate files from the rest of the objects).

Comment: ...valgrind, likewise, will be much more useful with debug symbols available. I'd actually consider starting there before gdb (or use valgrind with its --vgdb or --db-attach=yes options).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I just read that git is normally compiled with -g, and checking the Makefile in the source, it appears to be true.  However, when I start with "gdb git", it's saying no debug symbols were found.

Comment: I rather doubt that git itself is at fault here.  `strace` can tell you if it really is the exec failing (it probably is), but not necessarily why—although if it can decode the execve arguments, those must be OK.  Besides the "bad path" possibility there's also "bad arguments" and various internal kernel failures (although again these all seem unlikely).  Oh, and, the trace stuff is enabled by setting `GIT_TRACE=1` in the environment.

Comment: Again, symbol availability comes down to distribution packaging -- on modern Red Hat-derived distros, for instance, the debug symbols will be split out into separate files and stripped from the original executables after compilation; thus, it's conventional to compile **all** packages with debug symbols wherever populated, such that the associated `-debugsyms` packages (or local equivalent) are fully populated. There's precious little advice we can give here which will apply across all distros' packaging, other than to look into how your specific distribution handles debug symbols.

Comment: @user3391564: if that's the only strace output, it's definitely looking at the wrong command.  The error message must be coming from another (different) git process, as you say.  Maybe run strace with the flag for tracing children as well, so that you can see all of them...

Comment: Yes, that was the trick.  To run with -f.  Sure enough that's where the EFAULT is coming from: `execve("/home/n/bin/git_diff_wrapper", ["/home/n/bin/git_diff_wrapper", "HEAD:switch-monitor.sh", "/tmp/3izzOd_HEAD:switch-monitor."..., "c395381e4dea848d081739bc88d7965c"..., "100755", "/tmp/rlytSd_switch-monitor.sh", "1d9ee6d9a28e92fbf71e83550dac5abc"..., "100755", "master:./switch-monitor.sh", "index c395381..1d9ee6d 100755\n", 0x464649445f544947, 0x4f435f485441505f, 0x313d5245544e55, 0x53e9ad15, 0xf7a6aee], [/* 56 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
`

Comment: -v gives me the envp array, but I'd like to get it without all the "..." so I can try to run it from my own C program and see what happens.

Comment: I got what I think is the equivalent execve to what git does, and it also gave EFAULT when I ran it on it's own in an isolated script.  Doesn't seem like that alone totally absolves git, though.

Comment: @torek, if the strace output has some hex numbers among the argv array of strings, would that indicate that strace couldn't decode some of the arguments, and hence git is giving execve bad addresses?  Also, valgrind, still w/o debug symbols, says "execve(argv) points to unitialised bytes".  So does this sound like a bug in git?

Comment: That does look very suspicious.  The hex numbers are surely wrong.  Hard to see quite how git would fail like that though...

Comment: Aha, I checked out v1.9.1 and looked at the code.  There's an array of 10 `char *`s for the argv, which is filled with up to 11 items: `pgm`, `name`, ..., `other`, `xfrm_msg`, and finally `NULL`.  See `diff.c` starting around line 2917.  Array needs to be size 11 or more.  It's fixed in 2.0.x...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59229/discussion-between-user3391564-and-torek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer (copied from comments): it seems to be a bug in git 1.9.1.  The (old) `diff.c` code, around line 2910-2930 or so, fills in an array of size 10 with arguments, before calling the run-command code.  But in one case it puts in ten actual arguments and then an 11th `NULL`.  Depending on the whims of the compiler, the NULL may get overwritten with some other local variable (or the NULL might overwrite something important).

Changing the array to size 11 should fix the problem.  Or just update to a newer git (v2.0.0 or later); Jeff King replaced the hard-coded array with a dynamic one, in commits `82fbf269b9994d172719b2d456db5ef8453b323d` and `ae049c955c8858899467f6c5c0259c48a5294385`.

Comment: It works.  Thanks a lot for that help.  That was a slow and painful learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Note: another possible cause for bad address is the use of [`run-command.c#exists_in_PATH()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/63ab08fb9999bf9547c5279a8c2f0cdd8bb679ca/run-command.c#L213) by [`run-command.c#sane_execvp()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/63ab08fb9999bf9547c5279a8c2f0cdd8bb679ca/run-command.c#L221).
This is fixed with Git 2.25.1 (Feb. 2020).

See [commit 63ab08f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63ab08fb9999bf9547c5279a8c2f0cdd8bb679ca) (07 Jan 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 42096c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42096c778ddfcc946ea6fc302c46f96d586b5bab), 22 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`run-command`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63ab08fb9999bf9547c5279a8c2f0cdd8bb679ca): avoid undefined behavior in `exists_in_PATH`
>
> <sup>Noticed-by: Miriam R.</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>
> In this function, we free the pointer we get from `locate_in_PATH` and then check whether it's `NULL`.
>
> However, this is undefined behavior if the pointer is non-NULL, since the C standard no longer permits us to use a valid pointer after freeing it.
>
> The only case in which the C standard would permit this to be defined behavior is if r were `NULL`, since it states that in such a case "no action occurs" as a result of calling free.
>
> It's easy to suggest that this is not likely to be a problem, but we know that GCC does aggressively exploit the fact that undefined behavior can never occur to optimize and rewrite code, even when that's contrary to the expectations of the programmer.
>
> It is, in fact, very common for it to omit `NULL` pointer checks, just as we have here.
>
> Since it's easy to fix, let's do so, and avoid a potential headache in the future.

So instead of:

```
static int exists_in_PATH(const char *file)
{
    char *r = locate_in_PATH(file);
    free(r);
    return r != NULL;
}
```

You now have:

```
static int exists_in_PATH(const char *file)
{
    char *r = locate_in_PATH(file);
    int found = r != NULL;
    free(r);
    return found;
}
```